# Show value in validatorMessage

Tags: primefaces

I am using a validatorMessage for a regex I have for an email input, but I want to show the current value from the input in the message, at the place {0}.

But if I used the variable that is declared in the bean it doesn't work, because it doesn't process the variables because there is an validation error. How would I show the current value in the input in the validatorMessage?

Note: {0} is used in the PrimeFaces locales for the current value with validating.

```
<p:inputText id="email" value="#{registerBean.email}" type="email"  label="#{bundle.register_email}" required="true" style="width: 100%;" validatorMessage="#{bundle.register_email}: '{0}' #{bundle.register_email_error}">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
</p:inputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution I propose is to use a custom "messages.properties" file and overwrite the default messages of JSF API.

For an example of this file please redirect to: jsf-api-2.x.jar, "javax \ faces \ Messages.properties".
Take for example the two values found in the file messages.properties

[image]

```
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM={1}: Validation Error: Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}''

javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM={1}: Validation Error: Length is less than allowable minimum of ''{0}'
```

For example,

If maximum length validation failed, JSF gets “javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM”.
If minimum length validation failed, JSF gets “javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM”.

**Personalized Message**

Create a file (with any name) for exemple: myMessages.properties and place them in a specific package in your source folder.

Place in all the messages you find in the file of the messages.properties jsf-api-api 2.x.jar .
Then change the message as you like, for example:

```
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM=My custom message 1
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=My custom message 2
```

**Register Message Bundle**

Register your custom properties file in “faces-config.xml”, put it as Application level.

*faces-config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
 <application>
  <message-bundle>
    package.name.MyMessage
  </message-bundle>
 </application>
```

**Demo**

```
<h:form>

    <h:panelGrid columns="3">

        Enter your username :

        <h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" 
            size="20" required="true" label="Username">
            <f:validateLength minimum="5" maximum="10" />
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message for="username" style="color:red" />

        Enter your DOB :

        <h:inputText id="dob" value="#{user.dob}" 
            size="20" required="true" label="Date of Birth">
            <f:convertDateTime />
        </h:inputText>

        <h:message for="dob" style="color:red" />

    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="result" />

</h:form>
```

The source :  [click here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/)

Comment: Please improve this answer. Link only answers are not in line with Stackoverflow regulations

Comment: @Kukeltje it's ok ? I Edit them